# How can i sort a mysql result by a list of prioritised ids?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a large products database, and every sunday, my script is activating 50 new products.
the thing is, based on some rules in my script, im finding some products i should prioritize activating. (for your example, lets say it should always prioritize activating products with the name 'hello kitty' and 'meshuggah' in them, before everything else)

my db table contains info about the product, and unique id.
lets say that the script finds 5 of these ids, having hello kitty in the title.

so, how can i make the query, so that the prioritized items will come on top, and then followed by id desc?

here some pseudocode of what im after:

`SELECT * FROM products order by (id='59', id='47', id='28', id='29', id='20'), id desc limit 50`

the result should give me id 59, 47, 28, 29 and 20 first, then followed by other ids in the products table sorted by id descending.

is that possible in one query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `FIELD`

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
order by FIELD(id,59,47,28,29,20), id desc 
limit 50
```

- [Ordering by specific field values with MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)

Comment: ah, thanks, learn something new every day :) just had to add desc behind the field or else the field ids came out on bottom

Comment: @KristianRafteseth that's great `:D`

Comment: Note that this works because FIELD() returns 0 if the value of `id` (in this case) isn't found. By making the order DESC it sorts the zeros to the bottom and uses the second search term (here, `id`) to sort those.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your pseudo code also comes pretty close to such a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
order by id='59' desc, id='47' desc, id='28' desc, id='29' desc, id='20' desc, id desc
limit 50
```

This uses the fact that a condition evaluates to 0 or 1.